# Where do I initialize my webdriver in Django using Selenium along django.test

Tags: django, selenium, selenium-webdriver, django-testing, django-tests

I am willing to test my Django application using Selenium. From what I read, Django already cover the testing part and allow you to write your own tests.

Willing to use this with Selenium, here is my `<application>/test.py`:

```py
from some.path.to.my.utilitary.module import TestTools


class FormTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.webui = TestTools()

    def test_advanced_settings(self):
        self.webui.go_to('home')
        self.webui.click('id', 'button-advanced-settings')
        self.webui.click('id', 'id_setting_0')
        self.webui.click('id', 'id_setting_1')
        self.webui.click('id', 'id_setting_2')
        self.webui.click('id', 'id_setting_3', submit=True)

    def test_zone_selector(self):
        self.webui.go_to('home')
        self.webui.click('id', 'button-zone-selector')
```

I've written a Python class in which I implemented the Selenium logic (`TestTools`), so I can focus on writing test code in my Django applications:

```py
class TestTools():
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(...)
        ...

    # Those methods use self.driver to do things

    def click(...):
        ...

    def go_to(...):
        ...

    def quit(...):
        ...
```

I noticed I couldn't override the `__init__` method in the `TestCase` child, so I put the `self.webui = TestTools()` in the `setUp` method. However, it is called twice (for each test method I guess), and thus create 2 webdrivers.

What I want to do is running `./manage test`, opening only one browser and running all my tests upon it. Where should the webdriver initialization live ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my insight.

I prefer to create a custom `TestCase` based on [LiveServerTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase):

```
class SeleniumTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):
    """
    A base test case for selenium, providing different helper methods.
    """

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = WebDriver()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    def open(self, url):
        self.driver.get("%s%s" % (self.live_server_url, url))
```

Then, all my test cases are derived from this `SeleniumTestCase`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: since all your test cases are derived from `SeleniumTestCase`,  I am assuming that each test case is running on a different driver. If so, is it a bad thing to test every test case on the same browser ?

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, you should open up a new browser instance for every test, isolate each one from others. But, in case your tests requires a lot of time to run, and it's very critical for you - you can share browser instances between tests. Then, just replace `setUp` with classmethod `setUpClass` and `tearDown` with classmethod `tearDownClass`.